# Trimming whitespace in string variable

Tags: stata

I have a variable `acusip` that looks like this:

```
    000000111111
```

I need to eliminate black spaces at the end.

I know this function, but do not know the command:

```
strrtrim("acusip ")="acusip"
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for details on how to ask Stata-related questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate acusip1 = "000000111111      "
generate acusip2 = strtrim(acusip1)

list

     +-----------------------------------+
     |            acusip1        acusip2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. | 000000111111         000000111111 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Dimitar, if you found my answer helpful, please accept it using the check-mark. This is how you reward volunteers in this site for their time and ensure that they will help you again in the future.